# API for google apis console?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api-console

Is there any way how to access  https://code.google.com/apis/console with any kind of api? I need to access it with python and add subdomains to oauth2 callbacks dynamically, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no API to programmatically configure projects in the APIs Console.

Comment: that is sad, I though that google has something similat to aws, where I believe you can do everything dynamically...

Comment: Is this still the case as of June 2013?